# Laravel csv export error

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I want to generate csv and below is my code. but im getting   error

```
array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

## csv controller function

```
        $list = DB::table('festivals')
        ->join('namedesgs', 'festivals.id', '=', 'namedesgs.festival')
        ->select(DB::raw("festivals.id ,GROUP_CONCAT(namedesgs.name SEPARATOR '\n') as names,GROUP_CONCAT(namedesgs.designation SEPARATOR '\n') as namese"))
        ->groupBy('festivals.id')
        ->get();

    array_unshift($list, array_keys($list[0]));

$callback = function () use ($list) {
$FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($list as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $row[$key] = '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $val).'"';
    }
    fputcsv($FH, $row);
}
fclose($FH);
```

};

```
    return
```

Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toArray() function after get() to convert result collection into the array like following:

```
$list = DB::table('festivals')
        ->join('namedesgs', 'festivals.id', '=', 'namedesgs.festival')
        ->select(DB::raw("festivals.id ,GROUP_CONCAT(namedesgs.name SEPARATOR '\n') as names,GROUP_CONCAT(namedesgs.designation SEPARATOR '\n') as namese"))
        ->groupBy('festivals.id')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Then your below code will work okay!